# update xcode 6 to 7 (code doesn't work swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, webview, updates

I have a project swift with some webView ( I'm using WKWebView ) and it worked without any probles. 
I made a update of my xcode to 7.1 version and now none of my webview work. I have no error but i have nothing in my screen. if someone has a idea thanks

(sorry for my english)

```
 class Actu: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  {

/**** Variable declaration and IBoutlet *****/

    @IBOutlet weak var contact: UIBarButtonItem!
    var BackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem!
    var rightplayBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem!
    var refreshPageButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    var webView: WKWebView
    var varIntermediate = String()
    let urlContainer = StreamPlayer.sharedInstance.url

/**** Javascript Insertion *****/

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let scriptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hideSectionsActu", ofType: "js")
    let scriptContent = try? String(contentsOfFile:scriptURL!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent!, injectionTime: .AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
}
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   /**** View did Load *****/

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.BackButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Retour", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
    self.refreshPageButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: self, action: "refresh:")

    // Webview creation//
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([height, width])

    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .New, context: nil)

    let url = NSURL(string: "MyURL")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

}
///////////////////////////////////////////
func webViewFunction(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    let javaScriptString : NSString = "var el=document.getElementsByClassName(\"home-link\")[0];el.removeAttribute(\"href\");"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString as String, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

this is my code after "conversion" from xcode 7

Comment: Please share some code and some more info,  your question is too generic and vague for anybody to be able to give you an answer.  Chances are you exploited a bug that was fixed in 7, and the code needs to be rewritten

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I edited my post

Comment: try forcing the contraints to update on the viewdidappear function,  override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool){super.viewDidAppear(animated);self.updateViewConstraints();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pay attention to the following 2 tips:

1.Pay attention to this setting:

```
PROJECT/TARGETS -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Embedded Content Contains Swift Code -> YES
```

2.In your plist file,you should add this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

for you to request to non-https internet request if you rebuild your project with Xcode 7 or above.